# Appium XPath Selector returns WebDriverException

Tags: xpath, appium, appium-android

I'm attempting to perform some automation of an Android app, using NGTest framework and UIAutomator.

The below is output from UI Automator - my XPath knowledge is not the hottest but I've attempted to select the parent of the Camera button using the following Java code:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id=com.instagram.android:id/tab_bar']"));
```

However this returns an exception:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
```

Could anyone guide me better on how to use XPath expressions to drill down into the tree from UIInspector? Should I be starting at the top and working my way down, or is it ok to try and grab children in this way?

I have also tried grabbing the camera icon directly using the bounds, but that didn't work either.

Attempted:

```
WebElement abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@bounds,'[508,2119][571,2131]')']"));
    abc.click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a quote sign at the beginning of your resource-id value.
You are using:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id=com.instagram.android:id/tab_bar']"));
```

And it should be:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id= 'com.instagram.android:id/tab_bar']"));
```

[This element explorer can really help you locating the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUhak.png)